# How to determine file system or open unknown .img file

Tags: linux, file-format

I have a .img file which will not mount, open, extract or anything within Windows using either the tools built into Windows 10, WinRAR or 7-Zip, they all return errors.

I'm trying to look at data contained within the file which is destined for a Telenav system and would add an update to existing data - or overwrite. I do not know the file system of the .img file which makes life even more interesting.

I need some help pointing in the right direction as to how I may be able to view the information? It originally resided within a compressed folder. I'm fairly new to this stuff so please be gentle and guide me in the right direction if possible.

I do have a ubuntu machine but yet to try on that. Still a Linux newb.

I also can't add new tags so sorry if they're wrong too!

Comment: A good start would be to execute the two command-line programs `file` to get some basic information about the file and of course `binwalk`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd boot it up on a Linux (Mint) machine that I had and it comes up with the offset but unknown partition table

~/Desktop/test.img 20195573760B
Sector size 512B
Partition Table: unknown. When interrogating with 'file' it says 'DOS/MBR boot sector